# Invoke-WebRequest and reading a Table inside of a DIV

Tags: sql, powershell, html-table, datatable, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to read the table below with Invoke-WebRequest to read the table shown below, however I'm having a hard time getting that element's data. Below is an excerpt from the beginning of that table, which appears dynamic. I don't have access to the sql server. The TABLE is unnamed, so the closest static tag I have is an enclosing DIV, however after overcoming some browser simulation display issues, the display property is being set to "NONE" ? How can I overcome that to get the containing data and tables?

Powershell code below

[Edit 1]

Current code

```
$reqWithHeadersNonBasic = Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "http://xxxxx/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2Fxxxxx%20xxxxx%2Fxxxxx%20xxxxx%2Fxxxxx%20xxxxx%20Report&rc:showbackbutton=true" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "Cache-Control"="max-age=0"
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"="1"
}

$tables = $reqWithHeadersNonBasic.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('table')
foreach ($table in $tables) 
{
    if ($table.Id -eq "ReportViewerControl_fixedTable")
    {
        Write-Host "FOUND: " $table.Id;
        $tableFound = $table;
    }
}

foreach ($row in $tableFound.rows) 
{
    foreach ($cell in $row.cells) 
    {
        if ($cell.innerHtml -ne $null)
        {
            if ($cell.InnerHtml.Contains("VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx"))
            {
                Write-Host "[Row $($row.rowIndex), Cell $($cell.cellIndex)]: '$($cell.innerHTML)'" # has style set to none
            }
        }   
    }       
}
```

Is producing this:

```
<div id="VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl" role="main" style="display: none;">
```

And this produces no innerHtml

```
$divs = @($reqWithHeadersNonBasic.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("DIV")) 
$visibleDiv = $divs | where {$_.Id -eq "VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx"}

$visibleDiv.innerHTML
```

[empty]

```
$visibleDiv.outerHTML                                                       
<div id="VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx" role="main" style="display: none;">       
                                                                                                  
                                        </div>
```

[/Edit1]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" cols="6" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="A25956de757494f0691f1d17b42299dxxxxx"><tbody><tr height="0"><td style="width:38.10mm;min-width: 38.10mm"></td><td style="width:19.05mm;min-width: 19.05mm"></td><td style="width:92.08mm;min-width: 92.08mm"></td><td style="width:38.10mm;min-width: 38.10mm"></td><td style="width:44.45mm;min-width: 44.45mm"></td><td style="width:34.93mm;min-width: 34.93mm"></td></tr><tr valign="top"><td style="height:5.59mm;" class="A25956de757494f0691f1d17b42299dxxxxx"><div style="max-width:36.34mm;" class="A25956de757494f0691f1d17b42299xxxxx canGrowTextBoxInTablix cannotShrinkTextBoxInTablix" id="P8fbac2fe32c74726ac2c0ff52bbxxxxx_1_16iT0_aria"><div style="width:36.34mm;min-width: 36.34mm;">Current Step</div></div></td><td class="A25956de757494f0691f1d17b42299dxxxxx"><div id="P8fbac2fe32c74726ac2c0ff52bbxxxxx_1_20iT0" style="display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;"><div class="P8fbac2fe32c74726ac2c0ff52bbxxxxx_1_r18" lang="en-US" style="width:100%;display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;-ms-flex-flow: row;-webkit-flex-flow: row;flex-flow: row;"><div style="max-width:17.29mm;display: -ms-table-cell;display: -webkit-table-cell;display: table-cell;-ms-flex-flow: row;-webkit-flex-flow: row;flex-flow: row;" class="A25956de757494f0691f1d17b42299xxxxx canGrowTextBoxInTablix cannotShrinkTextBoxInTablix" id="P8fbac2fe32c74726ac2c0ff52bbxxxxx_1_20iT0_aria"><div style="width:13.06mm;min-width: 13.06mm;">CCB</div></div><div style="margin-left:auto;vertical-align:top"><a tabindex="1" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="var rp=$get('ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ReportControl');if(rp&amp;&amp;rp.control)rp.control.InvokeReportAction('Sort','20iT0_A',event);return false;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){var rp=$get('ReportViewerControl_xxxxx_xxxxx');if(rp&amp;&amp;rp.control)rp.control.InvokeReportAction('Sort','20iT0_A',event);return false;}"><img alt="Unsorted" border="0" src="/ReportServer/Reserved.xxxxx.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=14.0.600.1274&amp;Name=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RendererResources.unsorted.gif" style="float:left;"></a></div>
```

(Old for reference)

```
$userAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome;
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://xxxxx/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2Fxxxxx%20xxxxx%2Fxxxxx%20xxxxx%2Fxxxxx%20xxxxx%20Report&rc:showbackbutton=true" -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent $userAgent;

$ViewerControl = $req.ParsedHtml.getElementById("VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx");
$ViewerControl
```

This is the output of $ViewerControl (which is a parent div to the table I need) is below, how can I enumerate to the table and pull that data? Is there a way to dump the entire page and parse it manually?

```
className                        : 
id                               : VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx
tagName                          : DIV
parentElement                    : mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass
style                            : System.__ComObject
onhelp                           : 
onclick                          : 
ondblclick                       : 
onkeydown                        : 
onkeyup                          : 
onkeypress                       : 
onmouseout                       : 
onmouseover                      : 
onmousemove                      : 
onmousedown                      : 
onmouseup                        : 
document                         : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
title                            : 
language                         : 
onselectstart                    : 
sourceIndex                      : 329
recordNumber                     : 
lang                             : 
offsetLeft                       : 0
offsetTop                        : 0
offsetWidth                      : 0
offsetHeight                     : 0
offsetParent                     : 
innerHTML                        : 
                                   
                                                    
innerText                        : 
outerHTML                        : <div id="VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx" role="main" style="display: none;">
                                   
                                                    </div>
outerText                        : 
parentTextEdit                   : mshtml.HTMLBodyClass
isTextEdit                       : False
filters                          : 
ondragstart                      : 
onbeforeupdate                   : 
onafterupdate                    : 
onerrorupdate                    : 
onrowexit                        : 
onrowenter                       : 
ondatasetchanged                 : 
ondataavailable                  : 
ondatasetcomplete                : 
onfilterchange                   : 
children                         : System.__ComObject
all                              : System.__ComObject
scopeName                        : HTML
onlosecapture                    : 
onscroll                         : 
ondrag                           : 
ondragend                        : 
ondragenter                      : 
ondragover                       : 
ondragleave                      : 
ondrop                           : 
onbeforecut                      : 
oncut                            : 
onbeforecopy                     : 
oncopy                           : 
onbeforepaste                    : 
onpaste                          : 
currentStyle                     : System.__ComObject
onpropertychange                 : 
tabIndex                         : 0
accessKey                        : 
onblur                           : 
onfocus                          : 
onresize                         : 
clientHeight                     : 0
clientWidth                      : 0
clientTop                        : 0
clientLeft                       : 0
readyState                       : complete
onreadystatechange               : 
onrowsdelete                     : 
onrowsinserted                   : 
oncellchange                     : 
dir                              : 
scrollHeight                     : 0
scrollWidth                      : 0
scrollTop                        : 0
scrollLeft                       : 0
oncontextmenu                    : 
canHaveChildren                  : True
runtimeStyle                     : System.__ComObject
behaviorUrns                     : System.__ComObject
tagUrn                           : 
onbeforeeditfocus                : 
readyStateValue                  : 4
isMultiLine                      : True
canHaveHTML                      : True
onlayoutcomplete                 : 
onpage                           : 
inflateBlock                     : False
onbeforedeactivate               : 
contentEditable                  : inherit
isContentEditable                : False
hideFocus                        : False
disabled                         : False
isDisabled                       : False
onmove                           : 
oncontrolselect                  : 
onresizestart                    : 
onresizeend                      : 
onmovestart                      : 
onmoveend                        : 
onmouseenter                     : 
onmouseleave                     : 
onactivate                       : 
ondeactivate                     : 
glyphMode                        : 0
onmousewheel                     : 
onbeforeactivate                 : 
onfocusin                        : 
onfocusout                       : 
uniqueNumber                     : 3
uniqueID                         : ms__id3
nodeType                         : 1
parentNode                       : mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass
childNodes                       : System.__ComObject
attributes                       : System.__ComObject
nodeName                         : DIV
nodeValue                        : 
firstChild                       : System.__ComObject
lastChild                        : System.__ComObject
previousSibling                  : System.__ComObject
nextSibling                      : mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass
ownerDocument                    : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
dataFld                          : 
dataSrc                          : 
dataFormatAs                     : 
align                            : 
noWrap                           : False
IHTMLElement_className           : 
IHTMLElement_id                  : VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx
IHTMLElement_tagName             : DIV
IHTMLElement_parentElement       : mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass
IHTMLElement_style               : System.__ComObject
IHTMLElement_onhelp              : 
IHTMLElement_onclick             : 
IHTMLElement_ondblclick          : 
IHTMLElement_onkeydown           : 
IHTMLElement_onkeyup             : 
IHTMLElement_onkeypress          : 
IHTMLElement_onmouseout          : 
IHTMLElement_onmouseover         : 
IHTMLElement_onmousemove         : 
IHTMLElement_onmousedown         : 
IHTMLElement_onmouseup           : 
IHTMLElement_document            : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
IHTMLElement_title               : 
IHTMLElement_language            : 
IHTMLElement_onselectstart       : 
IHTMLElement_sourceIndex         : 329
IHTMLElement_recordNumber        : 
IHTMLElement_lang                : 
IHTMLElement_offsetLeft          : 0
IHTMLElement_offsetTop           : 0
IHTMLElement_offsetWidth         : 0
IHTMLElement_offsetHeight        : 0
IHTMLElement_offsetParent        : 
IHTMLElement_innerHTML           : 
                                   
                                                    
IHTMLElement_innerText           : 
IHTMLElement_outerHTML           : <div id="VisibleReportContentReportViewerControl_xxxxx" role="main" style="display: none;">
                                   
                                                    </div>
IHTMLElement_outerText           : 
IHTMLElement_parentTextEdit      : mshtml.HTMLBodyClass
IHTMLElement_isTextEdit          : False
IHTMLElement_filters             : 
IHTMLElement_ondragstart         : 
IHTMLElement_onbeforeupdate      : 
IHTMLElement_onafterupdate       : 
IHTMLElement_onerrorupdate       : 
IHTMLElement_onrowexit           : 
IHTMLElement_onrowenter          : 
IHTMLElement_ondatasetchanged    : 
IHTMLElement_ondataavailable     : 
IHTMLElement_ondatasetcomplete   : 
IHTMLElement_onfilterchange      : 
IHTMLElement_children            : System.__ComObject
IHTMLElement_all                 : System.__ComObject
IHTMLElement2_scopeName          : HTML
IHTMLElement2_onlosecapture      : 
IHTMLElement2_onscroll           : 
IHTMLElement2_ondrag             : 
IHTMLElement2_ondragend          : 
IHTMLElement2_ondragenter        : 
IHTMLElement2_ondragover         : 
IHTMLElement2_ondragleave        : 
IHTMLElement2_ondrop             : 
IHTMLElement2_onbeforecut        : 
IHTMLElement2_oncut              : 
IHTMLElement2_onbeforecopy       : 
IHTMLElement2_oncopy             : 
IHTMLElement2_onbeforepaste      : 
IHTMLElement2_onpaste            : 
IHTMLElement2_currentStyle       : System.__ComObject
IHTMLElement2_onpropertychange   : 
IHTMLElement2_tabIndex           : 0
IHTMLElement2_accessKey          : 
IHTMLElement2_onblur             : 
IHTMLElement2_onfocus            : 
IHTMLElement2_onresize           : 
IHTMLElement2_clientHeight       : 0
IHTMLElement2_clientWidth        : 0
IHTMLElement2_clientTop          : 0
IHTMLElement2_clientLeft         : 0
IHTMLElement2_readyState         : complete
IHTMLElement2_onreadystatechange : 
IHTMLElement2_onrowsdelete       : 
IHTMLElement2_onrowsinserted     : 
IHTMLElement2_oncellchange       : 
IHTMLElement2_dir                : 
IHTMLElement2_scrollHeight       : 0
IHTMLElement2_scrollWidth        : 0
IHTMLElement2_scrollTop          : 0
IHTMLElement2_scrollLeft         : 0
IHTMLElement2_oncontextmenu      : 
IHTMLElement2_canHaveChildren    : True
IHTMLElement2_runtimeStyle       : System.__ComObject
IHTMLElement2_behaviorUrns       : System.__ComObject
IHTMLElement2_tagUrn             : 
IHTMLElement2_onbeforeeditfocus  : 
IHTMLElement2_readyStateValue    : 4
IHTMLElement3_isMultiLine        : True
IHTMLElement3_canHaveHTML        : True
IHTMLElement3_onlayoutcomplete   : 
IHTMLElement3_onpage             : 
IHTMLElement3_inflateBlock       : False
IHTMLElement3_onbeforedeactivate : 
IHTMLElement3_contentEditable    : inherit
IHTMLElement3_isContentEditable  : False
IHTMLElement3_hideFocus          : False
IHTMLElement3_disabled           : False
IHTMLElement3_isDisabled         : False
IHTMLElement3_onmove             : 
IHTMLElement3_oncontrolselect    : 
IHTMLElement3_onresizestart      : 
IHTMLElement3_onresizeend        : 
IHTMLElement3_onmovestart        : 
IHTMLElement3_onmoveend          : 
IHTMLElement3_onmouseenter       : 
IHTMLElement3_onmouseleave       : 
IHTMLElement3_onactivate         : 
IHTMLElement3_ondeactivate       : 
IHTMLElement3_glyphMode          : 0
IHTMLElement4_onmousewheel       : 
IHTMLElement4_onbeforeactivate   : 
IHTMLElement4_onfocusin          : 
IHTMLElement4_onfocusout         : 
IHTMLUniqueName_uniqueNumber     : 3
IHTMLUniqueName_uniqueID         : ms__xxxxx
IHTMLDOMNode_nodeType            : 1
IHTMLDOMNode_parentNode          : mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass
IHTMLDOMNode_childNodes          : System.__ComObject
IHTMLDOMNode_attributes          : System.__ComObject
IHTMLDOMNode_nodeName            : DIV
IHTMLDOMNode_nodeValue           : 
IHTMLDOMNode_firstChild          : System.__ComObject
IHTMLDOMNode_lastChild           : System.__ComObject
IHTMLDOMNode_previousSibling     : System.__ComObject
IHTMLDOMNode_nextSibling         : mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass
IHTMLDOMNode2_ownerDocument      : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
IHTMLDatabinding_dataFld         : 
IHTMLDatabinding_dataSrc         : 
IHTMLDatabinding_dataFormatAs    : 
IHTMLDivElement_align            : 
IHTMLDivElement_noWrap           : False
IHTMLControlElement_tabIndex     : -32768
IHTMLControlElement_accessKey    : 
IHTMLControlElement_onblur       : 
IHTMLControlElement_onfocus      : 
IHTMLControlElement_onresize     : 
IHTMLControlElement_clientHeight : 0
IHTMLControlElement_clientWidth  : 0
IHTMLControlElement_clientTop    : 0
IHTMLControlElement_clientLeft   : 0
IHTMLTextContainer_scrollHeight  : 0
IHTMLTextContainer_scrollWidth   : 0
IHTMLTextContainer_scrollTop     : 0
IHTMLTextContainer_scrollLeft    : 0
IHTMLTextContainer_onscroll      :
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The following comment relates to the question you just deleted:

Comment: _Web scraping_ via `Invoke-WebRequest` / `Invoke-RestMethod` works only with _static_ content in the target page.
To support extracting content loaded _dynamically_, via JavaScript, you need a _full web browser_ that you can _control programmatically_, such as [Microsoft Edge via Selenium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium).
An increasingly limited alternative that will work with fewer and fewer sites over time is to use the _obsolete_ Internet Explorer and its `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object (apparently still a part of Windows as of Windows 11).

Answer (score 0):

> This is the output of $ViewerControl (which is a parent div to the table I need) is below, how can I enumerate to the table and pull that data?

Use `getElementsByTagName()` to locate the table, then iterate through the rows and their cells like this:

```
foreach ($table in $ViewerControl.getElementsByTagName('table')) {
  foreach ($row in $table.rows) {
    foreach ($cell in $row.cells) {
      Write-Host "[Row $($row.rowIndex), Cell $($cell.cellIndex)]: '$($cell.innerHTML)'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was out of the office. I've edited the post to reflect what I'm seeing now, in short I was getting a browser error because the sql server didn't recognize Invoke-WebRequest without adding session information and now that I'm able to drill down to the containing DIV for my table data, the style attribute is set to ' style="display: none"; ' . Can I overcome that?

Comment: I believe I'm getting 'style="display: none";' because Report Viewer doesn't like my WebRequest and browser spoofing?


    `Report Viewer Configuration Error
   
    Browser not supported
   </h2><p>Report Viewer requires a standards compliant browser. Users of Internet Explorer 8 and earlier should switch to a modern browser, or if already using a modern browser target standards mode by adding the &lt;meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" &gt; header tag to the host page.</p>
  </div>`